# can I use a variable variable such as $$var in PHP?

Tags: python

I have codes just like follows:

```
class test:
    def do_something():
        pass

test1 = test()
test2 = test()
test3 = test()
test4 = test()
test5 = test()
test6 = test()
test7 = test()
test8 = test()
test9 = test()
...
```

Now I need invoke each instance's function, just like that:

```
test1.do_something()
test2.do_something()
test3.do_something()
test4.do_something()
test5.do_something()
test6.do_something()
test7.do_something()
test8.do_something()
test9.do_something()
...
```

Too many classes, so I thought may be a for loop can complete the work:

```
for i in range(1, 30):
    ("test" + str(i)).do_something()
```

Of course it doesn't work, for string doesn't have do_something() function, can anyone have any idea to realize the function?

Comment: Why don't you just use an array?

Comment: Why would anyone use one of most useless programming language features ever?

Comment: The `$$` feature in PHP *really* is darn ugly. I wouldn't recommend anyone to ever use it.

Comment: @Griwes: I don't know Python (I saw PHP in the question title and initially assumed this was a PHP question), so not sure if your comment was aimed at me or at the OP.  If it's at me; what's wrong with arrays in Python?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, I was talking about using `testX` instead of `test[X]`, of course.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a `list` or `dict` to store your variables. For example:

```
class Test:
    def doSomething(self):
        pass

tests = [Test() for i in range(9)]

# Now to invoke the functions:
tests[0].doSomething()
tests[1].doSomething()
 ...
tests[8].doSomething()

# or if you want to do them all at once:
for item in tests:
    item.doSomething()
```

Comment: Minor nitpick: throws `TypeError: doSomething() takes no arguments (1 given)`.